# implementing for loop to check data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, web-services, webmethod

I want to be able to retrieve a template (fingerprint) from the database and compare this onto the current template captured using a fingerprint reader. I am using a web service but it is not working.

```
public fgrTemplate StuVerifications(int ID)
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'", cn);
            //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", i);
            SqlDataReader sd = com.ExecuteReader();
            while (sd.Read())
            {
                fgrTemplate fingerprint = new fgrTemplate()
                {
                    ID = sd.GetInt32(0),
                    StudentID = sd.GetInt32(1),
                    Description = sd.GetString(2)
                    //Template = sd.GetByte(3)

                };
                cn.Close();
                return fingerprint;

            }

            cn.Close();
            return new fgrTemplate();
```

the code below matches the two template

```
//3rd Step - Match against registered template


                    string[] fingerpos_str = new string[]
                                           {
                                              "Unknown finger",
                                              "Right thumb",
                                              "Right index finger",
                                              "Right middle finger",
                                              "Right ring finger",
                                              "Right little finger",
                                              "Left thumb",
                                              "Left index finger",
                                              "Left middle finger",
                                              "Left ring finger",
                                              "Left little finger"};

                    Int32 err;
                    SGFPMFingerPosition finger_pos = SGFPMFingerPosition.FINGPOS_UK;
                    bool finger_found = false;

                    SGFPMANSITemplateInfo sample_info = new SGFPMANSITemplateInfo();
                    foreach (fgrTemplate m_StoredTemplate in StudentVerifications(s.ID))


                    //err = m_FPM.GetAnsiTemplateInfo(m_StoredTemplate, sample_info);

                    for (int i = 0; i < sample_info.TotalSamples; i++)
                    {
                        bool matched = false;
                        err = m_FPM.MatchAnsiTemplate(m_StoredTemplate, i, m_VrfMin, 0, m_SecurityLevel, ref matched);
                        if (matched)
                        {
                            finger_found = true;
                            finger_pos = (SGFPMFingerPosition)sample_info.SampleInfo[i].FingerNumber;
                            // break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (err == (Int32)SGFPMError.ERROR_NONE)
                    {
                        if (finger_found)
                            richTextBox1.Text = "The matched data found. Finger position: " + fingerpos_str[(Int32)finger_pos];
                        else
                            richTextBox1.Text = "Cannot find a matched data";
                    }
                    else
                        richTextBox1.Text = "MatchAnsiTemplate() Error : " + err;
```

I want to be able to check each row in the database but having difficulties in doing so. how do i implement a for loop in this situation.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an IEnumerable like this:

```
public IEnumerable<fgrTemplate> StuVerifications(int ID)
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Template FROM tblFingerprint WHERE ID = '" + ID + "'", cn);
                //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", i);
                SqlDataReader sd = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (sd.Read())
                {
                    fgrTemplate fingerprint = new fgrTemplate()
                    {
                        ID = sd.GetInt32(0),
                        StudentID = sd.GetInt32(1),
                        Description = sd.GetString(2)
                        //Template = sd.GetByte(3)

                    };
                    yield return fingerprint;

                }

                cn.Close();
```

This will return a collection of fgrTemplates (one for each row) that you can then foreach through after.

Then to go through each template do something like this (Note I am guessing at how this method you want to loop works, so this may not be exactly right):

```
foreach(fgrTemplate t in StuVerifications(ID))
{
err = m_FPM.MatchAnsiTemplate(t, i, m_VrfMin, 0, m_SecurityLevel, ref matched);
if (matched)
      display student name
  else
      error message
}
```

Comment: thank you. how do I then apply the forloop in my application to get the stored template. sorry new to c#

Comment: Just edited the post -- Ps please upvote answers and comments you find helpful, and be sure to mark the correct answer once you have it

Comment: Hi im getting the error Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Registration.ServiceReference1.fgrTemplate' to 'byte[]' C:\Users\Frances\Documents\Backup\02-12-2013\Registration\Registration\frmRegistration.cs 246 51 Registration

Comment: That must be to do with that MatchAnsiTemplate method. I have no idea what that thing does or what the arguments are supposed to be. Do you have a description of what it does and what the arguments are?

Comment: Im using Secugen SDK. MatchAnsiTemplate() matches newly input template  (m_VrfMin) against registered template (m_storedtemplate).                 MatchAnsiTemplate(byte[] ansiTemplate1, int samplenum1, byte[]ansitemplate2, int samplenum2, securitylevel, ref bool matched)

Comment: Sounds like you need a way to convert your template object into a byte[]. I can't help you with that though. I don't know anything about Secugen SDK